# VSTO Ribbon disappearing on ClickOnce upgrade

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, outlook-addin

I have an add-in for OL2010 (written in C#) that works great.  It loads with no problems on my development system, and initial installations on test workstations goes smoothly.

When I make a change to the code and republish the installation, the ClickOnce upgrade runs, the add-in loads, but the ribbon that's part of the code does not appear.  I've verified that the add-in is loaded, so that's not the issue.  If I close Outlook, then re-open it, the add-in appears as it should.

Oddly, if I disable the add-in (when it's not visible), it appears.  When I re-enable it, it's still there and works fine.

Ideas?  I'm baffled.  Nothing was changed in terms of my ribbon code, so I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run your update while Outlook is open?

From past experience, Outlook "de-activates" your add-in if it gets updated.  You can restart outlook, or "activate" it from their terrible (almost unusable) add-in menu and it will reappear.

Is this what you are seeing?  As a test, close Outlook, then update your add-in.

Comment: The update runs on startup...i have my add-in checking for updates each time.

Comment: That is exactly what's happening then.  If your add-in's files get updated with Outlook running, you will have to restart Outlook or go to the file menu and "activate" it before it will show up.

Comment: oddly, none of the other add-ins that I created have this issue.  anything I can look for to remedy it?

Comment: Can you see if your other addins do anything differently?  Such as their setting for "Load at Startup" versus "Load on Demand" (this is in the ClickOnce Publish menu).  Check other settings also.

Comment: So then what is the difference between your addins that work during an update and the one that doesn't?